# Is it posible to make qtip look this way?

Tags: jquery, background, background-image, styling, qtip

i would like to know if I can make qtip bubble looke like this:

[image]

Please note that i'm using 4 images: left, center, right and bottom;

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't want you to guys serve it me done but i want to make sure that it's posible before I start and if you can give me a direction where to look or start.

```
<div class="qtip qtip-stylename">
   <div class="qtip-tip" rel="cornerValue"></div>
   <div class="qtip-wrapper">
      <div class="qtip-borderTop"></div> // Only present when using rounded corners
      <div class="qtip-contentWrapper">
         <div class="qtip-title"> // All CSS styles...
            <div class="qtip-button"></div> // ...are usually applied...
         </div>
         <div class="qtip-content"></div> // ...to these three elements!
      </div>
      <div class="qtip-borderBottom"></div> // Only present when using rounded corners
   </div>
</div>
```

The thing is i know how to set top/bottom images but not the left/right ones :s

Comment: I thought qtip had its own imageless rounded corner technique?

Comment: What are you doing?  qTip2 has it's own stylesheet you'd modify to get to this look.

Comment: @sparky672 using left, center, right and bottom images??

Comment: My point is:  **Why** are you creating this with images when the same can be done by simple modification to the CSS included with qTip2?

Comment: The borders are not one color, the have two colors (please zoom to the first image)

Comment: there are two borders, if you know what i mean. external gray and internal black! you can't see :O ???

Comment: Perfect vision and a color-sensor-calibrated 27-inch LCD...  I can barely perceive a slight difference in the border.

Comment: Well.. I know my designer will, so... :( Plus, as I said in a comment of next answer I need support to internet explorer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit: While my answer still largely applies, changes in qTip since this was posted have caused the CSS shown here to no longer be entirely accurate.  Some adjustments will be needed to fix this to work with newer versions.**

It's hard to tell exactly what your bubble image looks like due to the quality and size, but from what I can gather, it is very trivial to re-create that exact look in CSS as others have already mentioned.

I realize you didn't want this served done, but the best way to answer your question for me was to experiment and try to re-create it.  It's not completely done, however.  You'll have to tweak this to get it to work in non-webkit browsers (cough IE cough cough filter style cough) ;)

Basically, the key here is to wrap your tip contents in a container that you can use to create the double-border effect.

like I said though, it's hard to tell exactly what the border looks like.  If the outside border is just thicker and a different color (as it may be based on your comments), the same principle still applies, so you should be able to figure it out (Edit: see my 2nd demo of this below).  Good luck!

Here's my working demo on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kiddailey/7Re6a/1/

And here's an alternate version using padding and two transparent background colors to simulate the border instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/kiddailey/GDqyv/

The classes for the first demo are defined as follows:

```
.doubleborder .ui-tooltip-content
{
    background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.95);
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #444;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding: 1px;
}

.doubleborder .ui-tooltip-content div
{
    border: 1px solid #666;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.doubleborder .ui-tooltip-content h4 {
    font-size: 125%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And you'll also need to specify a custom tip size in your qTip2 init to get the smaller, squared tip:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center'
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'doubleborder',
        tip: {
            width: 6,
            height: 4
        }
    }

});
```

The second demo's classes are slightly different:

```
.doubleborder .ui-tooltip-content
{
    background-color: rgba(60,60,60,0.95);
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #555;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding: 2px;
}

.doubleborder .ui-tooltip-content div
{
    background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.95);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.doubleborder .ui-tooltip-content h4 {
    font-size: 125%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That's great! but when i place into my .html file the double border dissapears.. hm.. any clue?

Comment: even if I set padding:10px to the div.. :s

Comment: It's likely there is something that's overriding it.  If you're got Firebug handy, you can inspect the qTip element when they are displayed and see what the actual classes are that are being applied.  The other thing to check is that your qTip "classes" property matches your actual class names and doesn't include anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should abandon this way of adding rounded corners and use CSS3 which will be the minimal code to do this with a very cross browser comparability.

Example:

```
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;
```

Comment: i totally agree with you, but we need support to IE6/7 :( But also the radius is not a single color, it's like a double radious (black and grey (maybe you need to zoom it to check it out))

Comment: ok, i totally know that pain you face with IE uuuuuch!! so at this case i will suggest you use Tables instead of div's as it will ensure the location of the rounded corners and will not cause any positioning problem.

Comment: actually i have the layout ready. I wrote my custom tooltip plugin but i'm facing several problems... and just thought would might be easier to use qtip/qtip2: the plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256622/convert-this-custom-jquery-tooltip-script-into-a-jquery-plugin

Comment: As long as users see it, I personally think a square-cornered tooltip in IE6/7 is _enough_ support. image corners are just an antiquated practice from ye olde internet tymes.

Comment: But also the radius is not a single color, it's like a double radious (black and grey (maybe you need to zoom it to check it out))